# iOS text editor - save/load data model design?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, text

I'm currently developing a simple text editor for iPad, and only save/load data parts are left. As a novice programmer, I don't have any experience with data managements in other languages and development environments. I researched on Core Data for a week and implemented a basic auto save/load feature in my app. But I have questions about better design of a text editor's data management such as saving text to *.txt files.

Which way is better? How do other text editors

**1) Saving/Loading text as *.txt files**

I found that in iOS 3.2 and later, the app can save and load (sync) texts as *.txt files into its local folder, so the users can load files in iTunes easily.

My question is that to implement save/load features, **can I just save each text as *.txt file in my local folder and load them when launching my app**? Specifically, can I just load titles of each *.txt file and load the entire NSString content only if the user clicks the specific file in UITableView??

So it doesn't use Core Data (or maybe Core Data is just used for a current text for auto save).

**2) Core Data**

Or using only Core Data is better approach? So when only the users want to save text to a *.txt file, the app saves a Core Data object or NSString content to *.txt file. In other words, unless the users manually save text as *.txt files, the users can't see any *.txt file in iTunes because Core Data internally saves them.

**3) Both 1) + 2)**

Would it better to save text as *.txt files and also using Core Data? I think it's just wasteful though.

Sorry for long questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple strongly suggests in their Human Interface Guidelines that your users must not have "press save" to save, but rather saves should be automatic. At this point, iOS users do indeed expect that behavior. Core Data and autosave work really well together. (Core Data is also great for implementing Undo/Redo functionality as well.)

Therefore, I would suggest using Core Data as the app's internal format but offering the ability to export to other formats, like `.txt`. They are really not mutually exclusive methods. To export `.txt` files, you would create the `.txt` file in memory and then write it to your app's documents directory, which is what iTunes reads from. It's not very complicated.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use text files. So you can save space and sync into iTunes.